# Xamarin forms: Image Cache

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library, memorycache

Hi I am trying to build an app using xamarin forms PCL. I am implementing image gallery in which I have used a default image. All the images are on blob. I want to download image and cache that Image in device and as soon as download is complete I need to replace my default image with it.
And on loading app next time download image only if it is not present in cache.
I dont get any plugin for image caching and loading image from cache.
I have seen a plugin named FFPLUGIN but it didnt work.
Any idea how I can implement this? IMAGE CACHING

Comment: Are your images named dynamically or do they have a static `url` such as http://www.mywebsite.com/myimage.png?

Comment: @user1 dynamically named

Comment: web images are cached by default for 24 hours with `Xamarin.Forms.Image`. You can increase that by changing `CacheValidity`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the built in `ImageCaching` in Xamarin Forms shown here:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/#Downloaded_Image_Caching

> **Downloaded Image Caching**
>
> UriImageSource also supports caching of
>   downloaded images, configured through the following properties:
>
> **CachingEnabled** - Whether caching is enabled ( true by default).
>
> **CacheValidity** - A TimeSpan that defines how long the image will be
>   stored locally. Caching is enabled by default and will store the image
>   locally for 24 hours. To disable caching for a particular image,
>   instantiate the image source like this:
>
> ```
> Image.Source = new UriImageSource {CachingEnabled = false,
> Uri="http://server.com/image"}; To set a specific cache period (for
> example, 5 days) instantiate the image source like this:
>
>
> webImage.Source = new UriImageSource {
> Uri = new Uri("https://xamarin.com/content/images/pages/forms/example-app.png"),
> CachingEnabled = true,
> CacheValidity = new TimeSpan(5,0,0,0) };
> ```
>
> Built-in caching makes it very easy to support scenarios like scrolling lists of images, where
>   you can set (or bind) an image in each cell and let the built-in cache
>   take care of re-loading the image when the cell is scrolled back into
>   view.

Comment: But how will I check it if it is in cache or not

Comment: I want my images to download only if they are not in app cache

Comment: `Xamarin Forms Image` will do that check for you, and if not redownload the image

Comment: My app can run in offline mode also that is why I am looking for image cache. Will it make any difference if no internet is there?

Comment: If the application cannot download the `image` to the cache then no image will be displayed. Once the image is in the cache I suggest setting the `CacheValidity` to `Timspan.MaxValue` then the image will be cached forever

Comment: Then how my default image will come up then? I first need to set my local default image and then URI Image source?

Comment: Is there any callback function that I can use for getting the image download complete event? I need to catch image download event?